# UI Angular Bootstrap typeahead capture highlighted element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap typeahead. Is there a way to get the focused/highlighted element from the list of items in typeahead in our controller/directive? As shown in the image, I need to capture Illinois in my controller.I haven't selected Illinois but just focused on the option.

[image: refer this]

Comment: use jQuery to select active element. eg. $("[typeahead-popup]:active")